# Updating modal dialog while page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, coldfusion

I have a site written in Cold Fusion.  One of the pages is my main search area, which has a form that submits to my results.cfm page.  On results.cfm, I have several cfinclude template statements which call in each file that builds the page from what the user searched for.

Depending on what the user searches for, the page sometimes takes a while to load.  I'd like to show a modal dialog indicating the progress of the search.  Each included template on the results page has as the first line

```
<cfset session.progressStatus = "Loading [whatever it's loading]">
```

On my search form, I have it so that when the user submits the form, I'm showing the modal dialog.  That all works fine, however after the dialog is shown, I'm using the code below in an attempt to make an ajax call to a script that simply gives me the value of the session.progressStatus variable.  I thought by doing things this way, as the page loads the dialog would continue to show and would have it's text updated to reflect the current operation.  However, this is not the case.  The dialog text does not change.  What is really strange, is when I click search and the dialog is displayed, if I hit the escape key the dialog text starts to get updated accordingly, but the page stops loading.

```
        progressTimer = setInterval(function(){
        $.get("ajax/ajax_get_progress.cfm", { type:"progress" }, function(result){
            result = result.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
            console.log('result is: ' + result);
            progressMessage = (result=="") ? "Performing Search" : result;
            $progressIndicatorMessage.html(progressMessageStart + progressMessage + progressMessageEnd);
        });
    }, 1000);
```

Anyone have any idea as to WHY??  I'm very confused.

Comment: I think a modal dialog box is a bad way to approach this situation.  There are much better ways to amuse the user while a page is processing.  As far as why the escape key stops the page from loading, that's default browser behaviour.

Comment: @DanBracuk better ways to amuse the user while the page is processing....suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In response to, " better ways to amuse the user while the page is processing....suggestions?", ...,

[Here are some references for a progress bar.](https://www.google.ca/#q=coldfusion%20progress%20bar)

Another option is to instantly display an image file in a div with  and cfflush, then when the page has processed, replace the contents of the div.  This will entail the use of cfsavecontent and javascript.  [Here are some links](https://www.google.ca/#q=coldfusion+refresh+div).

Another option, display the image as described above.  Use cfsavecontent, but with a session variable.  Then use cflocation to go to another page where you output the session variable.  This is probably the simplest option, plus, it will probably disregard pressing the escape key.  You'll have to verify that.